# What type of screwdriver should I use to change the light bulb in my range hood?

Tags: hood

I have a MODEL # INCA HC HILO72 hood range 
One of the light bulbs has burnt out.  Tried to take out the light bulb but the screws are way too tight and afraid of stripping it.  What type of screwdriver should I use?  Already disassembled the part to make it easier to work on too.
Note:  I am a female asking for assistance.  Thanks

Comment: I found a post for changing the lights on your model and the owner mentioned removing screws but not what kind of screws. http://www.justanswer.com/appliance/56jvs-trying-replace-halogen-light-bulb-faber-range.html My answer below may not apply to your unit. can you post a photo of the screw. ?

Comment: A straight slot screwdriver will do the trick. The Manuel did not provide an exact size but you want the blade thickness to fill the slot , not a lot of slop will help prevent problems.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok i posted all of this and THEN saw the model was of a different number. It is the only INCA HC unit i see on there website i think it may be the same or close enough let me know if these instructions apply. i will leave up the info and amend if i can find the exact unit, [faber contact page](http://www.faberonline.com/contact/).

After a little searching  i found the documentation for . [your unit](http://www.faberonline.com/hoods/inca-hc/)

[installation and use PDF](http://www.faberonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Inca-hc-2016-install.pdf)

AND

[Parts PDDF](http://www.faberonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/incahcss2016-parts.pdf)

[image: replacement instructions]

[image: bulb type]

I would suggest you replace the halogen bulbs with led bulbs. Your bulbs have a base that is called a GU10 BASE. they now make LED bulbs with that base such as these.
[led gu10 bulbs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EWBZLBK) They will last for decades as opposed to replacing halogens **frequently** and will use much less energy than halogens.

When you get your old bulb out you can take it to the store to make sure you get a bulb with the same base and the same size so it will fit in your unit. You may find em at the big box stores or you may need to go to a lighting store.

Having change a few of these i should say they can be persnickety. you kinda gota push in on em while turning em and there usually is nothing grab on to for purchase. Make sure you fingers are dry and oil free and push just the right amount. its tricky.

> NOTE: i am a man who does not assume that because you are a woman you need my assistance. :)